# Using XML Schema to validate language

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm writing an XSD for an XML file encoded in UTF-8, which can possibly contain many languages which are not ASCII English.

Is there a possible way to validate that only certain languages (specifically languages which don't use the English alphabet like Hebrew or Arabic) would pass validation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions in a pattern facet to control what character set may appear, for example

```
<xs:pattern value="\p{IsHebrew}*"/>
```

but I've no idea how you would take advantage of that in practice: most languages allow use of foreign scripts e.g. when referring to the name of a foreigner.

Do take care to distinguish character set from encoding. They are quite different concepts. A pattern facet like this says what characters may appear, it doesn't constrain how they are encoded.